# Using cx_freeze in PyQt5, can't find PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, pyqt5

I want to build a standalone binary file for `windowz(xp, 7, ...)` from my `python3(+ PyQt5)` script and I inevitably use `cx_freeze` because other freezing apps do not work with python3 (like `py2exe`, `pyinstaller`).

I read the `cx_freeze` docs and lots of stackoverflow asks ans use this config for `setup.py‍‍‍` file :

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path_platforms = ( "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll", "platforms\qwindows.dll" )

includes = ["atexit","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui", "PyQt5.QtWidgets"]
includefiles = [path_platforms]
excludes = [
    '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
    'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
    'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter'
]
packages = ["os"]
path = []

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
                     "includes":      includes, 
                     "include_files": includefiles,
                     "excludes":      excludes, 
                     "packages":      packages, 
                     "path":          path
}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
exe = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    exe = Executable(
      script="D:\\imi\\aptanaWorKPCworkspace\\azhtel\\tel.py",
      initScript = None,
      base="Win32GUI",
      targetDir = r"dist",
      targetName="tel.exe",
      compress = True,
      copyDependentFiles = True,
      appendScriptToExe = False,
      appendScriptToLibrary = False,
      icon = None
    )

setup(  
      name = "telll",
      version = "0.1",
      author = 'me',
      description = "My GUI application!",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [exe]
)
```

run with:

```
python D:\imi\aptanaWorKPCworkspace\azhtel\setup.py build
```

This is my library that I used:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys
from telGui import Ui_MainWindow
import mysql
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
```

and this is my files in workspace:

[image: list of workspace files]

But this error happened (or another kind of errors).

[image: error pic]

Why this happened and what config for `setup.py` is good for pyqt5 app ??

## Thanks.

Python3.3, PyQt5, Mysqlconnector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with find another directory near the dist directory called `build` and all library files are in there, i delete `targetDir = r"dist"` part of `setup.py` and everythings is alright !

Comment: Yep - setting targetDir on the Executable alone puts it in a different directory from the rest of the files it needs. This is confusing, so I've filed [an issue](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/41/specifying-targetdir-on-an-executable) for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try pyinstaller. It's much better than cxfreeze.