# Exception: Cannot find PyQt5 plugin directories when using Pyinstaller despite PyQt5 not even being used

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyinstaller

A month ago I solved my applcation freezing issues for Python 2.7 as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135408/using-pyinstaller-on-parmap-causes-a-tkinter-matplotlib-import-error-why). I have since adapted my code to python 3.5 (using Anaconda) and it appears to be working.  couldn't get pyinstaller working with Anaconda so switched to trying to generate an .exe using the standard Python 3.5 compiler. I am using the same settings as in the link above (`pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. --clean --win-private-assemblies pipegui.py`), except I get the following error message instead:

```
`Exception: Cannot find PyQt5 plugin directories`
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207746/using-cx-freeze-in-pyqt5-cant-find-pyqt5) may be related? Except I'm using Pyinstaller and I don't have a setup.py so don't know how I can make use of the solution there, if at all

I find this error message bizarre because I am not using PyQt5, but PyQt4. Here is the full output:

```
C:\Users\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\PycharmProjects\Mesoscale-Brain-Explorer\src>pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. --clean --win-private-assemblies pipegui.py
62 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2
62 INFO: Python: 3.5.0
62 INFO: Platform: Windows-10.0.14393
62 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\PycharmProjects\Mesoscale-Brain-Explorer\src\pipegui.spec
62 INFO: UPX is not available.
62 INFO: Removing temporary files and cleaning cache in C:\Users\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller
62 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\\PycharmProjects\\Mesoscale-Brain-Explorer',
 'C:\\Users\\Cornelis Dirk '
 'Haupt\\PycharmProjects\\Mesoscale-Brain-Explorer\\src']
62 INFO: checking Analysis
62 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
62 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
62 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
62 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
1430 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
1727 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1742 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1742 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1758 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1758 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1774 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1774 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1774 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1789 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1789 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-conio-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1789 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-process-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1805 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: C:\Anaconda3\api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 695, in getImports
    return _getImports_pe(pth)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 122, in _getImports_pe
    dll, _ = sym.forwarder.split('.')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
1805 INFO: Caching module hooks...
1805 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\PycharmProjects\Mesoscale-Brain-Explorer\src\pipegui.py
1992 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2055 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
3181 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
3181 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\cornelis dirk haupt\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
4298 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
9975 INFO: Loading module hooks...
9975 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-_tkinter.py"...
10121 INFO: checking Tree
10121 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
10122 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
10184 INFO: checking Tree
10184 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
10185 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
10198 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
10404 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
10526 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
10526 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
10527 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.linalg.py"...
10527 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py"...
10529 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-plugins.py"...
10721 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt4.uic.port_v3
10726 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt4.uic.port_v2
12402 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-OpenGL.py"...
12583 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt4.QtGui.py"...
12802 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
12807 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt4.uic.py"...
12812 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
12813 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
12813 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
12814 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py"...
12814 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Cornelis Dirk Haupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 470, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 409, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 376, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 725, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 385, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 806, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py", line 15, in <module>
    binaries = qt_plugins_binaries('codecs', namespace='PyQt5')
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 64, in qt_plugins_binaries
    pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\cornelis dirk haupt\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 38, in qt_plugins_dir
    raise Exception('Cannot find {0} plugin directories'.format(namespace))
Exception: Cannot find PyQt5 plugin directories
```

I will say I also have no clue what to make of the `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054527/python-3-5-typeerror-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str) may be related? I only use binary mode with pickle a handful of times as far as I can tell this is my only usage:

```
pickle.dump( roiState, open( fileName, "wb" ) )
roiState = pickle.load(open(fileName, "rb"))
```

I don't have any errors when I run the application, only getting these errors when trying to generate an .exe using pyinstaller. Why?

Note also that Anaconda3 does pop up in the traceback above (why is it looking for binaries there?) but I:

1. Uninstalled pyinstaller from Anaconda
2. Am using the standard Python 3.5 (64-bit) compiler

Only thing I can think of that may be the culprit is that I'm no longer using the developer version of Pyinstaller (it just flat does not run in Python 3.5). I had to use the developer version to solve my freezing issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135408/using-pyinstaller-on-parmap-causes-a-tkinter-matplotlib-import-error-why) when my code was written for python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall Anaconda and everything works... I conclude that you simply cannot have Anaconda installed and use the standard Python 3.5 compiler at the same time if you're using Pyinstaller. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728108/running-pyinstaller-after-anaconda-install-results-in-importerror-no-module-nam) is related.

This is not the [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398710/2734863) time that uninstalling Anaconda appears to solve my issues... If I should report this issue somewhere please comment below. I don't know where.

Comment: To my understanding, the issue with conda is like this. If it is not available under current environment, it will look into base environment.

Answer (score 17):

I managed to fix the same problem I encountered (conda 4.5.4, pyinstaller 3.4) without uninstalling conda:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

conda already installed PyQt when I used `conda install jupyter seaborn`. Interestingly, using `conda install PyQt5` does not fix my problem. I don't know why. In any case I hope this may help someone out there.

Comment: To my understanding, the issue with conda is like this. If it is not available under current environment, it will look into base environment. So, if we install it with pip, then it will ensure correct environment is being used.

Comment: Under circumstances of conda 4.6.14 and conda installed pyqt 5.9.2, I **can't install PyQt5 through pip install PyQt5**, which causes a compatibility error. Referring to [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56438976/7398586), installing the latest version of PyInstaller works for me.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers on this post worked for me, but I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369108/cannot-convert-python-script-into-an-executable-using-pyinstaller-empty-dist-fo) from a few months ago and it worked. Linking it here in case others run into a similar problem and come across this thread before the other one.

The solution is to add `--exclude-module PyQt5` after the pyinstaller statement.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is an issue with the current version of pyinstaller. I uninstalled the default version.

`pip uninstall pyinstaller`

and installed the latest trial version

`pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

and then it worked for me.

More information here: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3938

Answer (score 2):

[specifically for an anacodna installation] I had the same problem, but it got fixed when I updated anaconda. 
From the Anaconda prompt: `conda update anaconda`. This updates several packages including pyqt

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (whicle trying to convert to .exe a script named **main.py** ) is a variation of [kierabeth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11574118/kierabeth). More specifically the following:

1. first create a spec file and exclude the PyQt5 module

   ```
   pyi-makespec --onefile main.py --exclude-module PyQt5
   ```
2. then build the spec file

   ```
   pyinstaller main.spec
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This still looks like an issue, which is why I'm resurrecting this old post in the event someone like me googles for a fix to the same issue.

You don't need to uninstall or reinstall anything. I just installed latest version of Anaconda and pyinstaller and have come across the same error again.

The problem is the ../Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py file.

The solution lies in the following link.
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3938

```
            json_str = exec_statement("""

            # ... some code here ...

            else:
                # QLibraryInfo isn't always valid until a QCoreApplication is
                # instantiated.
                app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv) # this is the part that's needed
```

I hope the pyinstaller devs fix this at some stage.

Comment: Please quote the relevant section(s) from the linked page in your answer.