# Pyinstaller Exception: Cannot find PyQt4 plugin directories

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I will spare unnecessary details here and try to keep it short.

My issue:  I built my program using the following in command prompt

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo.ico H:\<script location>
```

Originally, this compiled and output perfectly fine.  I opened up the exe to test it, and it worked like a charm.  However, I noticed a small typo of mine and adjusted my script to fix it.  When I went to use the same command prompt line to build the .exe again is when it gave me the PyQt4 error.  This actually happened earlier today as well, to which I solved it my uninstalling both PyInstaller and PyQt4, restarted my computer, then re-installed them.  Everything else I tried just did not work.

I do not understand how it would work at one moment and then, literally not even 30 seconds later, it gives me this exception.  I would prefer not to constantly uninstall and then re-install PyQt4 and PyInstaller in order to build my .exe files.

I am running python 3.5 through idle if that makes any difference here.
I do not have any other form of python installed either.
I have been downloading my packages using pip and from the wheels located at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ if that also makes a difference.

I saw the solution here [Exception: Cannot find PyQt5 plugin directories when using Pyinstaller despite PyQt5 not even being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736000/exception-cannot-find-pyqt5-plugin-directories-when-using-pyinstaller-despite-p) .  However, I do not have Anaconda installed that could be interfering like this guy found.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I sincerely have no Idea but all I can think about is temporary files. Is the only thing that it may have change between the first time and second one. Try to clean the cache and delete the build folder before re-building again

Comment: Uninstalling the reinstalling PyQt4 on its own appears to work, albeit a shoddy fix at best.  Oh well, it isn't that much of a burden for a simple and fast command to execute.