# Converting py file to exe, Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm quite new to phyton and I've just finished my first application.
Now, I'm trying to compile my .py file to an .exe buy that doestn seem to work.
I've looked everywhere for a solutio to my problem, but I just cant seem to find one.

When I run this command: pyinstaller gui.py

this error shows up:

```
4815 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4815 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4913 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4913 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
5019 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
5019 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
5096 WARNING: Unable to find Qt5 translations C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/translations\qtbase_*.qm. These translations were not packaged.
5096 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 241, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 500, in assemble
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 410, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\imphook.py", line 377, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 736, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 399, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 823, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 682, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 684, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py", line 11, in <module>
    hiddenimports, binaries, datas = add_qt5_dependencies(__file__)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 514, in add_qt5_dependencies
    more_binaries = qt_plugins_binaries(plugin, namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 132, in qt_plugins_binaries
    pdir = qt_plugins_dir(namespace=namespace)
  File "c:\users\ivo\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 117, in qt_plugins_dir
    """.format(namespace, ", ".join(paths)))
Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/plugins
```

My path variable:

```
C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Ivo\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\scrcpy-windows-v1.0\adb.exe;D:\xampp2\php;C:\Users\Ivo\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Ive been trying to fix this for a whole day now, if anyone could help me/ point me in the right direction that would be greatly appericiated.

edit:

Also, since i've reinstalled some things to try and fix the problem. the file wont start and gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ivo\Documents\temp\project\gui.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 8):

Conda 4.5.11,
Python 3.6.4,
PyInstaller 3.4

The plugin path is determined incorrectly in hooks/qt.py. Qt requires that QCoreApplication is instantiated first, before any other calls.

My qt.py hook is in ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py.

I edited it like so:

```
    json_str = exec_statement("""
        import sys

        # exec_statement only captures stdout. If there are
        # errors, capture them to stdout so they can be displayed to the
        # user. Do this early, in case PyQt5 imports produce stderr
        # output.
        sys.stderr = sys.stdout

        import json
        from %s.QtCore import QLibraryInfo, QCoreApplication

        # QLibraryInfo isn't always valid until a QCoreApplication is
        # instantiated.
        app = QCoreApplication([])
        paths = [x for x in dir(QLibraryInfo) if x.endswith('Path')]
        location = {x: QLibraryInfo.location(getattr(QLibraryInfo, x))
                    for x in paths}
        try:
            version = QLibraryInfo.version().segments()
        except AttributeError:
            version = None
        print(str(json.dumps({
            'isDebugBuild': QLibraryInfo.isDebugBuild(),
            'version': version,
            'location': location,
        })))
    """ % self.namespace)
```

see [1](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3740).

Comment: How can we do this without editing the hook from within the conda environment? By updating qt or something? I feel very uncomfortable messing with the .py file itself

Comment: I am far from an expert, but I couldn't find another way to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the fix in [Exception: Cannot find PyQt5 plugin directories when using Pyinstaller despite PyQt5 not even being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736000/exception-cannot-find-pyqt5-plugin-directories-when-using-pyinstaller-despite-p/52602963#52602963). In short:

`pip intall PyQt5`

Note that,  strangely enough, `conda install PyQt5` may not fix the problem.

I encountered the same problem and saw another suggestion: make the missing directory (C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/plugins in your case) and copy the two files pyqt5.dll and pyqt5qmlplugin.dll (presumably somewhere in c:\Users[name]\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs) to the directory.

I did not try it since I fixed the problem with `pip install PyQt5`. You may want to give it a try.

Comment: Where does that odd subdirectory name come from?  (In your case, it's
    `C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/plugins` )?  
This question isn't directly to you, but to anybody reading this.  I got a completely different directory, but the "create wierd directory" solution worked for me too (not just installing)

Comment: Since the Exception complained:
**_Exception:
        Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
        Paths checked:
        C:/qt5b/qt_1524647842210/_h_env/Library/plugins_**

Comment: @ cong you - I should have been clearer in my comment.  It was not meant for you.  I was asking if anybody else knew why the directory in your message is different from mine, even though it's basically the same message.   How does the pyinstaller create that directory name, since yours is different from mine, and neither of them existed on my system.\

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.6.3 with ANACONDA3 and Spyder as IDE. Pyinstaller 3.4.

Trying to generate an exe file with **Pyinstaller**, I had two kinds of errors:

1. **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' "**. This was resolved by 
        **updating each module** imported in the Python script, with :
                 **pip install --upgrade <*module_name*>**
2. **"Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories"** :this was the next error. As 
    mentioned by **cong yu** in his previous post, I fixed this problem by running 
                 **pip install PyQt5**
3. Do not forget to upgrade **setuptools**  to the latest version as well

The process delivered an exe file which I have not yet tested.
But at least, I got Pyinstaller reaching the end without failing in error.

Hope this could be helpful

And, by the way, Happy New Year :)

**Edit**:

I have tested the standalone **.exe** produced by **py2exe**
The program is running and get to the end without errors.

But the problem is that **xlsx** is no more running, because no Excel 
files are created. These files are based on **pandas** dataframes.
My hint is that **pandas** module, which is the main core of the program, 
seems to be altered. I noticed that the dataframes used were truncated, 
through the control lines edited in the **Ipython** console in **Spyder**.

I think that my best alternative is to reinstall **Anaconda3**.

So be careful, upgrading the modules used in the program you want as 
standalone with **py2exe**. It seems that upgrading pandas module was a 
mistake.

I am sorry, if I gave a bad advice in my main post, but upgrading was the 
best way to run **py2exe**. Be careful with the upgrade of **pandas**.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Anaconda. There have been issues in the past. If not you can try py2exe that is fairly decent too.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the **latest version of PyInstaller**, then this exception of `"Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories"` is **addressed**.

You can install the latest version of PyInstaller through the [following command](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html):

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tarball/develop
```

> P.S: Some information about my setup:

```
$conda info
      conda version : 4.6.14
conda-build version : 3.17.8
     python version : 3.7.3.final.0
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.6.14 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763

$ pip show pyinstaller
Name: PyInstaller
Version: 3.5.dev0+d74052489
Summary: PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package.
```