# Problems with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, geopandas

I would like to bundle an application into an executable using PyInstaller. I am having issues because of the `geopandas` library. Currently my script `throwaway.py` contains only the following import:

`import geopandas`

However running `pyinstaller throwaway.py` does not work. It appears to have problems with `PyQt5` which only `matplotlib` imports.

The log for `pyinstaller`is too long to include here however the following shows the last exception encountered:

```
Exception:
            Cannot find existing PyQt5 plugin directories
            Paths checked: c:/qt/qt_1489878162099/_b_env/Library/plugins
```

I am not sure how to approach this, but there are a couple of conceptual options:

- Find a way to exclude the geopandas import of matplotlib. I am not using matplotlib so I don't really need it to be packaged in the first place
- Figure out why this problem is occurring and prevent/fix it

What can I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by downloading the development version of `pyinstaller` as follows:

`pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

I got the above from [this link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3750). The current `conda-forge` distribution of `pyinstaller` still does not include [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376313/converting-py-file-to-exe-cannot-find-existing-pyqt5-plugin-directories) which is included in the development version. The code prior to that change is what was causing the error in the question to occur.

Hopefully the `conda-forge` distribution will soon come to incorporate this into the main distribution.

So basically if you are experiencing this problem you have two choices:

- Install development version of PyInstaller and use that
- Manually go inside the `~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py` and modify the file as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376313/converting-py-file-to-exe-cannot-find-existing-pyqt5-plugin-directories)

Answer (score 2):

This `pyinstaller -y -d --clean throwaway.py` works for me.

[image]

Also, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662773/cannot-import-geopandas-with-pyinstaller-executable-despite-running-fine-in-th).

There is an issue with the recursing limit, stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977929/pyinstaller-creating-exe-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-ca/42419584#42419584).
Try to increase it like this:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Comment: Works for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Python 3.7, fresh install of geopanda

Comment: I am using python 3.6.6 from within an anaconda environment. I also just updated my `geopandas` doing `conda update geopandas` and still get the error. My project requires the use of `python 3.6.6` so I have no choice here

Comment: Check if recursion limit (in my answer) do the job

Comment: I added the `setrecursionlimit` before my `geopandas` import. Same problem.

Comment: For some, it worked by adding it into the spec file (to the beginning of the spec file) and then run pyinstaller filename.spec

Comment: Still the same problem. I think its a deeper underlying problem.