# No hook files generated by PyInstaller

Tags: hook, pyinstaller

In the PyInstaller [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/hooks.html) the following is stated:

> The name of a hook file is hook-full.import.name.py, where
>   full.import.name is the fully-qualified name of an imported script or
>   module. You can browse through the existing hooks in the hooks folder
>   of the PyInstaller distribution folder and see the names of the
>   packages for which hooks have been written.

However in my [current attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116243/problems-with-pyinstaller/53116366) to generate an executable for my script, after running I see that there is no `hooks` folder in the `dist` folder generated.

Am I looking in the wrong folder? Where are my hook files being dumped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs state

> You can browse through the existing hooks in the hooks folder of the
>   ***PyInstaller*** distribution folder

and not

> You can browse through the existing hooks in the hooks folder of the
>   ***distribution*** folder

Which means that you cannot expect to find the hooks in the `dist` folder generated by running

`pyinstaller test.py`

You must find them, for the anaconda case, in:

`Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks`

For other environments you can also check in the site-packages directory