# Pyinstaller Creates Empty Dist Folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a small python script where I have only one dependency

```
from pandas import DataFrame as pdf
```

I want to create a `.exe` that would only require users to have python installed in their `PATH`. [This guide](http://www.pyinstaller.org/index.html) helped me run the creation but the yielding dist folder is empty. Does anyone know why this is the case or

what I am doing wrong?

**Specs:** written in and for `Windows OS`, `Python 3.6.5` - Anaconda

**Edit:** Here's the sample I am working with.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as pdf
if "__main__":
    df = pdf([['This', 'is'], ['a', 'Test']],
                     index=['Row 1', 'Row 2'],
                     columns=['col 1', 'col 2'])
    df.to_excel("output\output.xlsx")
```

The resulting `spec` file is

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['src\\sample.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\kpiq\\Documents\\Data Science\\Executable Creation'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='sample',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='sample')
```

The command used was `pyinstaller src\sample.py`

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No everything runs successfully.

Comment: Then you will need to post your python script, the `.spec` file that `Pyinstaller` creates, and the command that you run to create an `.exe` file.

Comment: See edits above.

Comment: Are you sure the `dist` directory is completely empty? `Pyinstaller` should create a `sample` directory inside the `dist` directory. And the `.exe` should be in that directory. By the way, if your `Pyinstaller` is successful, then even `Python` is not required to be installed in order to run the resulting `.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Because I had Avast anti-virus installed on my computer it detected my new executable as a malware and it deleted it immediately after compilation and I had to disable for a while like until next restart and then I tested my new app.

You can also try running `pyinstaller yourapp.spec` in your app directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer posted by NAP_time in another question [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736000/exception-cannot-find-pyqt5-plugin-directories-when-using-pyinstaller-despite-p).  The solution was to download the trial version using:

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip

I did this and it worked for me.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip

i have the same problem earlier but after trying this i was able

Comment: You should explain that this installs the latest development version of pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue.  For me, my anti-virus flagged the newly created .exe as potential malware and removed it.  Once I launched my AV and instructed it to consider the file safe, it showed back up in the dist folder and worked fine.