# Cannot convert Python script into an executable using Pyinstaller: Empty dist folder & PyQt5 not found

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to create a stand-alone executable file from my Python script. The Python script was created by Python 3.7.1 and I use Anaconda.

When I run Pyinstaller, it creates a .spec file and build and dist folders. However, the dist folder is empty.

No errors were reported by Pyinstaller apart from "cannot find existing pyqt5 plugin directories".

How can I solve this problem? Or how I can troubleshoot it so I can understand where the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

After several hours reading different threads I have finally found an acceptable solution.

I added:

```
--exclude-module PyQt5
```

to exclude PyQt5 since my scrip doesn't use it. The exe is created.

Hope it can help someone.